# How to Randomize a Collection and use Pagination in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I am trying to randomize a collection and at the same time use pagination.

There is a simple way to retrieve N random documents from a collection using `$sample` like this (even though it does not guarantee duplicate documents):

```js
db.mycoll.aggregate([ { $sample: { size: 20 } } ])
```

But I would like to be able to randomize a collection and then fetch 20 documents at a time from that randomized collection.

This is an example of how I want it to work:

```js
const randomizedCollection = await db.mycoll.randomize()

randomizedCollection.skip(0).limit(20) // first 20
randomizedCollection.skip(20).limit(20) // second 20
```

I can't figure out a way to do this and would appreciate any help or feedback!

Comment: You misuse the tool. $sample is for ... hm, sampling, not randomising.  There is $rand to generate random number. Add a field with random number and sort on it. The only thing, it will work only within cursor - i.e. you need to use .getMore() for pagination.  My guts tell me you are making a web app / API, and are going to use new cursors for each page. If so, the only way to do that is to create materialised view and deal with consequences.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you for your help! Yes, I am building an API so there would be a new cursor for every page. Would you store the entire query result in S3 for example?

Comment: hmm, how come S3 just popped in? Apparently S3 is new regex of the cloud age =)  "some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use S3" Now they have two problems." There are at least half-dozen options how to implement pagination with random order, some are better for one usecases, other for others. There is nothing out of box in Mongo. Please  talk to a solution architect to find the most appropriate way to achieve the result. SO format is not quite suitable to capture requirements and design architecture.